# Java,Double comparison , if ((BMI) >= 18.5 || (BMI) <= 24.9) , the condition is true while BMI=25.77777777777778

Tags: java, if-statement, double

This is just a simple Java code but gets a wrong result:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMI_Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your weight(kg):");
        double w = s.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("\n%s", "Enter you height(cm):");
        double h = s.nextDouble();
        h = h / 100;

        double BMI = w / (h * h);

        String b;

        if (BMI < 18.5) {
            System.out.println("less than 18.5");
            b = "Underweight";
        } else if ((BMI) >= 18.5 || (BMI) <= 24.9) {
            System.out.println("between 18.5 and 24.9");
            b = "Normal";
        } else if (BMI >= 25 || BMI <= 29.9) {
            System.out.println("between 25 and 29.9");
            b = "Overweight";
        } else {
            System.out.println("greater than 30");
            b = "Obese";
        }

        System.out.println("Your BMI is:" + BMI + "(" + b + ")");

    }

}
```

This is the output

> Enter your weight(kg):58
>
> Enter you height(cm):150
>
> between 18.5 and 24.9
>
> Your BMI is:25.77777777777778(Normal)

I thought it might be related to precision of double variable, I tried the same code declaring the variables as float instead of double and got the same result , I really don't understand how could such a thing happen (25.7 < 24.9)?! how?!

Comment: it's not 25.7 that is < 24.9 but rather 25.7 > 18.5. You might use && instead of ||.

Comment: Well you said it yourself: `(BMI) >= 18.5` OR `(BMI) <= 24.9)` which means that if any of this sub-conditions is `true`, entire expression should be evaluated to `true` (remember that `true OR false` == `true`). What you are looking for is `AND`. You can think of `OR` and `AND` as `sum` and `intersection` of ranges, so `x>2 OR x<10` is `R`, while `x>2 && x<10` gives us range `(2; 10)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
else if ((BMI) >= 18.5 || (BMI) <= 24.9)
```

The or (`||`) needs to be an *and* (`&&`). You want to check that the BMI is within the range.

(Do this for the next `else if` as well.)

Comment: Oh my God! what a mistake , seems that I was really asleep while writing the code , Thanks a lot :)